# Using Cookie Data For WP_Query Loop

Tags: php, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, cookies

I'm trying to retrieve data set in a cookie and use this to run a query.

I've set the cookie in functions.php like so;

```
add_action( 'init', 'resultsCookie' );
function resultsCookie() {

   setcookie( 'your-results', '18,17,11,8,10,27,26', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
```

While I can echo the string, I can't seem to get this functioning within the query;

```
$cookie_array = $_COOKIE["your-results"];

// Test output              
echo $cookie_array;

$sug_args =  array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post__in' => array( $cookie_array )
);

$sug_query = new WP_query ($sug_args);

if($sug_query->have_posts()) : while($sug_query->have_posts()) : $sug_query->the_post();

  // Run Loop                   
  wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of data type is there in `$_COOKIE["your-results"]` ? If this is an array, you don't need to wrap this within `array( $cookie_array )`. Try `(array) $cookie_array;` instead.

Comment: Just a string '18,17,11,8,10,27,26'. Strangely, it seems to pick out the first id just fine; for example '18'. However, the suggested tweak doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode the comma separated string to get the array of IDs. Follow the below code.

```
$cookie_array = $_COOKIE["your-results"];

// Test output              
echo $cookie_array;

$cookie_array = array_map( 'absint', (array) explode(',', $cookie_array) );

$sug_args =  array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post__in'  => $cookie_array,
);

$sug_query = new WP_query ($sug_args);

if( $sug_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while( $sug_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $sug_query->the_post();

        // Run Loop                   
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 

    endwhile; 
endif; 

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Works like a charm!

Comment: Great, Worked like a charm, Thank you so much :)